# Replacement for NSLayoutManager class in iOS

Tags: ios, text, drawrect

Is there any replacement class for NSLayoutManager in iOS? I want to draw vertical text just like in UITableView index view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CTFramesetter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html) in [CoreText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

iOS7 has it's own [NSLayoutManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html).